# How to clone a HTML element with its events without Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery, we can clone an element and all its events with `clone()` method. Example:

```
$(".element").clone(true);
```

How can we do the same thing with native Javascript?

*I'm updating my post.*

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
myelement = oldelement.cloneNode(deep)
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode):

> The Node.cloneNode() method returns a duplicate of the node on which
>   this method was called.
>
> **deep** ***Optional***
>
> true if the children of the node should also be cloned, or false to
>   clone only the specified node.

Comment: How to clone and object that is not a DOM node?